# Web2py: where to set T.set_current_languages()

Tags: internationalization, web2py

I'm trying to internationalise my app, and I want to set `T.set_current_languages('en', 'en-en')` as described in the [docs](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Determining-the-language). But it's unclear to me which file to place this in. Can I just stick it in e.g. db.py? Or at the top of default.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the setting to apply to all requests, then put it in a model file (e.g., db.py, as you suggest). If you put it at the top of the default.py controller, it will apply only to requests made to the default controller.

Comment: It is not working for me. It stays on the default all the time. It reads from languages/default.py

Comment: You might want to post a new question with code and more details.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/web2py/yebach%7Csort:date/web2py/A29561LVYVQ/Jb3bRlUxAQAJ